# How can I use a frame in apply?

Tags: r

I really like using the frame syntax in R. However, if I try to do this with apply, it gives me an error that the input is a vector, not a frame (which is correct). Is there a similar function to mapply which will let me keep using the frame syntax?

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

# This works, but is hard to read because you have to remember what's
# in column 1 
apply(df, 1, function(row) row[1])

# I'd rather do this, but it gives me an error
apply(df, 1, function(row) row$x)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense to me (perhaps because it's not reproducible), but have you looked at `ddply`?  It seems like you don't really need the 'multiple' functionality of `mapply` here.

Comment: @Ari: Sorry, this more generally applies to the whole family of `apply` functions, and I guess just plain apply works best here.

Comment: @Arun: I'm not sure what you mean? I want it to be a frame, not a matrix.

Comment: @Xodarap what do you mean by frame? data.frame I guess..and by the syntax of a frame you mean the $ accessor? I would ask the question like this : I have a data in a data.frame, I need to subset it according to some criteria(you explain the filter condition) to compute the mean of foodshare. I tried to do this using xxapply function but without success. What is the best manner to do it? of course all this have no sense without a reproducible example.

Comment: @agstudy: Yes, I know how to write my function using the column numbers (e.g. `function(x) x[5]`) but I'd rather use the $ accessor (`function(x) x$foo`).

Comment: @Arun: That error isn't coming because the input `gidd` is a vector, it's coming because `row` is a vector and I'm trying to use `$` on it. I know I can fix the error by using column numbers, but I want to use `$`.

Comment: @Arun: Gave another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youcab't use the `$` on an atomic vector, But I guess you want use it for **readability**.  But you can use `[` subsetter.

Here an example. Please provide a reproducible example next time. Question in R specially have no sense without data.

```
set.seed(1234)
gidd <- data.frame(region=sample(letters[1:6],100,rep=T),
                   wbregion=sample(letters[1:6],100,rep=T),
                   foodshare=rnorm(100,0,1),
                   consincPPP05 = runif(100,0,5),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)

  apply(gidd, ## I am applying it in all the grid here!
          1, 
        function(row) {
        similarRows = gidd[gidd$wbregion == row['region'] &
                         gidd$consincPPP05 > .8 * as.numeric(row['consincPPP05']),
                       ]
    return(mean(similarRows$foodshare))
  })
```

Note that with apply I need to convert to a numeric.

You can also use `plyr` or `data.table` for a clean syntax , for example:

```
  apply(df,1,function(row)row[1]*2)
```

is equivalent to

```
  ddply(df, 1, summarise, z = x*2)
```